# Wordpress MailChimp using button click instead of pop-up failing with 404 error

Tags: wordpress, mailchimp

I have never used MailChimp Easy Forms before. I'm trying to make the pop-up apear when a user pressing a button instead of the pop-up to just showing when the user gets to the website.

My js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup- forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script>

<script>
    function showMailingPopUp() {
        alert('inside the button click');

        require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function (L) {
            L.start({
                "baseUrl": "mc.us1.list-manage.com", "uuid": "81016de6debaf524b31df317af5480b1-us17",
                "lid": "8517f84634"
            })
        })
        document.cookie = "MCEvilPopupClosed=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
    }
</script>
```

And the HTML:

```
 <button id="open-popup" onclick ="showMailingPopUp();">Email signing</button>
```

In the inspection tool I get this error:

[image: Error from MailChimp]

This is how it looks in MailChimp:

[image: MailChimp]

Currently i'm using the listid from MailChimp as "lid" and my API-key as "uuid" and I think it's the uuid that break, but what is the uuid? If it's not the id's thats wrong what is it then?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

Install Easy Forms for MailChimp WordPress Plugin and set the mailchimp API key and it will fetch all of your list now create new form  and assign list with it then save it one shortcode will generate.

Now open one pop up using jquery and in content paste the shortcode then it will work.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/yikes-inc-easy-mailchimp-extender/

Comment: I have already installed Easy Forms for MailChimp. The Form is assigned with a mailchip API-key. I'm not sure what you mean about shortcode? do you have a working example?

Comment: Please find the link below:https://connect.mailchimp.com/integrations/yikes-inc-easy-mailchimp-extender-for-wordpress

Comment: I found the link, but what do I need that for? The Easy Forms for MailChimp is up and running. I need the Form to pop-up when a user presses a button on my website :-S

Comment: Yeah just follow the screenshot you will found the form shortcode and use the shortcode.

Comment: But I want the button to be a hard coded button from my header.php file in my wordpress theme?

Comment: I decided to make a specific page for MailChimp in my Wordpress theme so it's okay now, but the answear was not the one I was looking for :-)